# How to create an elseif condition in a script with Runspaces

Tags: multithreading, powershell

In the original script, I was attempting to search for a string in a text file in a running log. It worked fine however, since there is a -wait parameter in the loop, it wasn't easy to find a solution that would allow for the same script to search over multiple text files. Since then the following script was introduced to me that incorporates Runspaces:

```bash
using namespace System.Management.Automation.Runspaces
using namespace System.Threading

# get the log files here
$LogGroup = ('C:\log 0.txt', 'C:\Log 1.txt', 'C:\Log 2.txt')
# this help us write to the main log file in a thread safe manner
$lock     = [SemaphoreSlim]::new(1, 1)

# define the logic used for each thread, this is very similar to the
# initial script except for the use of the SemaphoreSlim
$action = {
    param($path)

    $PSDefaultParameterValues = @{ "Get-Date:format" = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" }
    Get-Content $path -Tail 1 -Wait | ForEach-Object {
        if($_ -match 'down') {
            # can I write to this file?
            $lock.Wait()
            try {
                Write-Host "Down: $_ - $path" -ForegroundColor Green
                Add-Content "path\to\mainLog.txt" -Value "$(Get-Date) Down: $_ - $path"
            }
            finally {
                # release the lock so other threads can write to the file
                $null = $lock.Release()
            }
        }
    }
}

try {
    $iss = [initialsessionstate]::CreateDefault2()
    $iss.Variables.Add([SessionStateVariableEntry]::new('lock', $lock, $null))
    $rspool = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, $LogGroup.Count, $iss, $Host)
    $rspool.ApartmentState = [ApartmentState]::STA
    $rspool.ThreadOptions  = [PSThreadOptions]::UseNewThread
    $rspool.Open()

    $res = foreach($path in $LogGroup) {
        $ps = [powershell]::Create($iss).AddScript($action).AddArgument($path)
        $ps.RunspacePool = $rspool
        @{
            Instance    = $ps
            AsyncResult = $ps.BeginInvoke()
        }
    }

    # block the main thread
    do {
        $id = [WaitHandle]::WaitAny($res.AsyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle, 200)
    }
    while($id -eq [WaitHandle]::WaitTimeout)
}
finally {
    # clean all the runspaces
    $res.Instance.ForEach('Dispose')
    $rspool.ForEach('Dispose')
}
```

The Runspaces allow for additional threads allowing for multitasking but I am not very skilled and I need help adding an elseif clause after an if statement. But my attempts were rewarded with the following error:

```
cmdlet ForEach-Object at command pipeline position 2 
Supply values for the following parameters: 
Process[0]:
```

Here’s the best I could come up with so far:

```bash
$action = { 
    param($path) 
    
    $PSDefaultParameterValues = @{ "Get-Date:format" = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" } 
    
    $lock.Wait() 
    # can I write to this file? 
    try { 
        Get-Content $path -Tail 1 -Wait | ForEach-Object 
            if($_ -match 'down) { 
                Write-Host "Down: $_ - $path" -ForegroundColor Red 
                Add-Content "C:\ log_down.txt" -Value "$(Get-Date) Down: $_ - $path" 
            } 
            elseif($_ -match 'up') { 
                Write-Host "Down: $_ - $path" -ForegroundColor Green 
                Add-Content "C:\ log_up.txt" -Value "$(Get-Date) up: $_ - $path" 
            } 
            $lock.Wait() 
        }
        
    finally { 
        # release the lock so other threads can write to the file 
        $null = $lock.Release() 
    } 
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the only change you need to do, below code only addresses the `$action` [Script Block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7.2). Rest of the code should remain the same.

Make sure you're using the **Full Paths of the logs**.

```
$action = { 
    param($path) 
    
    $PSDefaultParameterValues = @{ "Get-Date:format" = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" } 
    Get-Content $path -Tail 1 -Wait | ForEach-Object {
        # wait to enter the SemaphoreSlim
        $lock.Wait()
        try {
            if($_ -match 'down') { 
                Write-Host "Down: $_ - $path" -ForegroundColor Red 
                Add-Content "C:\log_down.txt" -Value "$(Get-Date) Down: $_ - $path"
            }    
            elseif($_ -match 'up') { 
                Write-Host "Up: $_ - $path" -ForegroundColor Green 
                Add-Content "C:\log_up.txt" -Value "$(Get-Date) up: $_ - $path"
            }
            # more conditions can go here
        }
        finally {
            # release the lock so other threads can write to the file 
            $null = $lock.Release() 
        }
    }
}
```

After closer look at your attempt, it seems almost right:

1. Missing an opening `{` after `ForEach-Object`.
2. Missing a closing `}` before the `finally` block.
3. [`.Wait()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim.wait?view=net-6.0#system-threading-semaphoreslim-wait) should be inside the loop instead of outside.

Comment: awesome! I’ll give it a try by tonight or tomorrow. Not at a pc at the moment.

Comment: Santiago Squarzon  So I was close. So glad to hear. I felt I was on the verge of getting it. Thanks

Comment: Yes Santiago Squarzon, that did it. The above code works to perfection. Now I'm able to add an elseif to this code. Thank you for the comments in the code. They really help me to learn how the code actually works so that I can make modifications myself in the future. Take care my friend.